# Shortcut to open Input Assistant

Tags: keyboard, autocomplete, input

*tl;dr* the answer is `F2`

How can I re-open the Input Assistant after I've mistakenly closed it?

E.g. Write the command `Plot`and press Esc. Now the assitant is gone. How do I open it with a shortcut?

There has to be some shortcut to open it again, right? In many IDEs `Ctrl+Space` is the standard shortcut for calling the autocomplete-y thingies but it doesn't work here.

As of now both documentation pages [How to use Input Assistant](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/UsingTheInputAssistant.html) and [Keyboard Shortcut Listing](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html#1519079882) fail to include this information.

Answer (score 4):

Just press `F2`

(I cant accept my own answer as an answer now as a new user)

Comment: Now, `F2` doesn't work. May you know the new key fot re-open the Input Assistant?

Answer (score 2):

On Windows:

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+k, for the input assistant

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+k, for argument documentation

Answer (score 0):

In MAC , place cursor just after the junction. An "i" pop up  will appear just next to the cursor. Click here and the documentation will reappeared.